# IOS: unwind segues from other tab

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a tab bar controller with two tabs. The first tab is a table view with overview data. When you click on a cell, it segues to a new view controller and shows detailed data. Data is passed between.

If I am on the segued detailed view and switch tabs, the detailed view persists.

On the second tab, you can switch which group you are viewing, therefore switching the data. I have the data reloading in the table, but when I switch tabs the detailed page still contains the old data until I hit the back button.

Is there a way to unwind the first tab's segue from the second tab when switch groups and reload data?

Comment: Show you example code please. So people know what you miss.

Comment: Are you really asking how to *unwind* the first tab's segue, or is it enough to simply *reload* the detailed page when you switch tabs?

Comment: @NRitH  I need to unwind the first tab's segue.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should be able to access your tab bar and within it the view controller and then do a pop, like so:

```
let tabBar = self.tabBarController
tabBar?.viewControllers?[0].navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

taking advantage of optinal chaining, basically you are saying: try to find the nearest **UITabBarController** then get the **UIViewController** in the tab bar position 0, then get the **UINavigationController** if there's one and then do a **pop** which means go a step back in the navigation chain.